# Passing String to DatabasHelper and using it in a query to search for an average between two tables

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, helper

Sorry I'm sorta new to this. I'm build an android app using java. I'm trying to pass two Strings to my DatabaseHelper class to query my database. This my method to retrieve to my Strings to the databasehelper.

private void retrieveDataFromSqlite(){

```
    String selectedYear = String.valueOf(dateViewer.getYear());
    String selectedMonth = String.valueOf(dateViewer.getMonth() +1);
    String selectedDay =  String.valueOf(dateViewer.getDayOfMonth());

    String date = (selectedYear) + '-' + (selectedMonth) + '-' + selectedDay;
    String email = textViewName.getText().toString();


    Data dataSetter = new Data();
    dataSetter.setDate(date);
    dataSetter.setEmail(email);

    String x;
    x = databaseHelper.viewData();

    textViewSugar.setText(x);
}
```

This is my databasehelper.

```
public String viewData(){
    //String x = "No Data For That Date";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Data dataGetter = new Data();
    String x = dataGetter.getEmail();

    //final String MY_QUERY = "SELECT AVG(data) FROM data INNER JOIN user ON data.email = user.user_email";
    db.close();
    return x;
}
```

I also have a data class with my getters and setters.
public class Data {

```
private int data_id;
private int userId;
private int data;
private String email;
private String date;

public int getData_id(){ return data_id; }
public void setData_id(int data_id){ this.data_id = data_id;}
public int getUserId(){ return userId;}
public void setUserId(int userId){ this.userId = userId;}
public int getData(){return data;}
public void setData(int data){ this.data = data;}
public String getEmail(){return email;}
public void setEmail(String email){ this.email = email;};
public String getDate(){return date;}
public void setDate(String date){this.date = date;}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new Data instance inside the function viewData

```
public String viewData(){
Data dataGetter = new Data();
}
```

which has no connection to the retrieveDataFromSqlite function's Data object.

Instead of creating a new data object in your viewData function, simply pass the datagetter and then get the value from it

```
public String viewData(Data dataGetter){
    //String x = "No Data For That Date";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String x = dataGetter.getEmail();

    //final String MY_QUERY = "SELECT AVG(data) FROM data INNER JOIN user ON data.email = user.user_email";
    db.close();
    return x;
}
```

then pass the data from retrieveDataFromSqlite function like

```
x = databaseHelper.viewData(dataSetter);
```

Comment: If it did i would request you to accept or up vote the answer, Thankyou.